# Re.search returns None, can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: python

As a beginner, I apologize if the answer is obvious to some.

I wrote a code to extract specific keywords and list them in the order that they were in the dataset, or text.
Eventually, I got an "error", as in, the re.search didn't find anything from the test file, even when it did have several of the searched words.
import re

```
datatofilter = open("S:/Töö/Meilikood/Meilide txtd/veb 21/test1.txt", "r")
linecount = 1
setcount = 0
set = ["one", "two"]
text = datatofilter.readline()
while text:
    text = datatofilter.readline(linecount)
    match = 0
    fromset = set[setcount]
    linesearch = re.search(fromset, text)
    #if (linesearch == None) is False:
    print(linesearch)
        #match = 1
    setcount =+ 1
    linecount =+ 1
    if text == "stopcode":
        break
datatofilter.close()
```

The "test1.txt" is precisely:

```
one, two
2
3
one, two
one
stopcode
```

Attempting to run the code printed exactly 30 lines of "None" (without the apostrophes)

Having searched Stack Overflow and finding several threads similar to my problem, I still do not have an idea why it does not work.

Comment: Did you mean linecount +=1 instead of linecount =+1?

Comment: Are you aware that `readline(1)` reads one _character_, not one _line_?